# Why is my accuracy decreasing with increasing K in KNN algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I am working on Pima Indian dataset and using KNN as my classification algorithm. In order to find the right k I am using KFold CV. However as the value of k increases the accuracy is decreasing.

```
knn_train = train_data.copy()
knn_y = knn_train['Outcome']
knn_train.drop('Outcome', axis=1, inplace=True)

acc_score = []
avg_score_lst = []
n_neighs_lst = []

for k in range(50):
  kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=23, shuffle=True)
  model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k+1) 

 for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(knn_train):
    X_train, X_test = knn_train.iloc[train_index,:], knn_train.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train, y_test = knn_y.iloc[train_index], knn_y.iloc[test_index]

    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds = model.predict(X_test)

    acc = accuracy_score(y_test, preds)
    acc_score.append(acc)

  avg_acc_score = mean(acc_score)

  avg_score_lst.append(avg_acc_score)
  n_neighs_lst.append(model.n_neighbors)

sns.lineplot(x=n_neighs_lst, y=avg_score_lst)
plt.show()
```

[Accuracy vs k graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXDzD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Predictions are made by averaging across the k neighbours. Where k is larger, the distance is then larger, which defeats the principle behind kNN - that neighbours that are nearer have similar densities or classes.

There is normally an optimum k, which you can find using cross-validation - not too big and not too small. However, it depends on your data - it's not impossible for a k of 1 to be optimal.